# Converting array of struct to array of pointers fails

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type test struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    foo := []test{
        {Name: "a"},
        {Name: "b"},
    }
    var bar []*test
    for _, item := range foo {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", item.Name)
        bar = append(bar, &item)
    }
    
    for _, item := range bar {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", item.Name)
    }
}
```

When I run the code above, I expect to see the output

```
a
b
a
b
```

However, the output is

```
a
b
b
b
```

What's going on?

For reference, this was done in the go playground

Comment: The loop reuses the same pointer. Add `fmt.Printf("%p\n", &item)` to the loop to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang src

```
// len_temp := len(range)
// range_temp := range
// for index_temp = 0; index_temp < len_temp; index_temp++ {
//     value_temp = range_temp[index_temp]
//     index = index_temp
//     value = value_temp
//     original body
//   }
```

Range is actually a *syntax sugar* for the `for` loop.  Internally it still uses a `for` loop and it will first copy all the elements of the `array` and loop through them and assign each index and value to a `temp` variable. When retrieving the address of the value, it actually takes the address of the `temp` variable and the new `array` would actually has every element points to the same address.

To fix

```
for i, _ := range foo {
    p := foo[i]
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",  p.Name)
    bar = append(bar, &p)
}
```